# How to shorten SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

According to my code below, I was using `cursor` to get all information in `WInstance` table. However, my query may have a problem with **performance** due to `cursor`. Is there any way to use nested-select instead of `cursor`? Please share me your idea.

My business here is to get only 1 of the same `ItemID`, `SequenceID`, `TaskStatus`, `ListID`, `WebID`, `SiteID`.

Technically, there are lots of the same `ItemID`, `SequenceID`, `TaskStatus`, `ListID`, `WebID`, `SiteID` in the joining tables of `WInstance` and `WProgress` with `AssignTask = 'Assign task'`. Therefore, I used `distinct` and `cursor`to loop through to get only the top 1 with `order by`.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CustomTasksHistory
    (
      @Username NVARCHAR(255)
    )
AS
    DECLARE @TempTableStatus TABLE
        (
          ItemID INT ,
          SequenceID INT ,
          TaskStatus NVARCHAR(25) ,
          ListID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
          WebID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
          SiteID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        );

    DECLARE @ItemID INT;
    DECLARE @SequenceID INT;
    DECLARE @ListID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @WebID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @SiteID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @AssignTask VARCHAR(25);
    SET @AssignTask = 'Assign task';

    -- Select final TaskStatus of each ItemID with its SequenceID --
    DECLARE cursor_ItemID CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                WI.ItemID ,
                WP.SequenceID ,
                WI.ListID ,
                WI.WebID ,
                WI.SiteID
        FROM    dbo.WInstance WI
                INNER JOIN dbo.WProgress WP ON WI.InstanceID = WP.InstanceID
        WHERE   WP.CurrentActivityTitle = @AssignTask;

    OPEN cursor_ItemID;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_ItemID INTO @ItemID, @SequenceID, @ListID, @WebID, @SiteID;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO @TempTableStatus
                    ( ItemID ,
                      SequenceID ,
                      TaskStatus ,
                      ListID ,
                      WebID ,
                      SiteID
                    )
                    SELECT TOP 1
                            WI.ItemID ,
                            WP.SequenceID ,
                            CASE WHEN WP.ActivityComplete = 0
                                 THEN 'Not Started'
                                 ELSE 'Completed'
                            END AS 'TaskStatus' ,
                            WI.ListID ,
                            WI.WebID ,
                            WI.SiteID
                    FROM    dbo.WInstance WI
                            INNER JOIN dbo.WProgress WP ON WI.InstanceID = WP.InstanceID
                    WHERE   WP.CurrentActivityTitle = @AssignTask
                            AND WI.ItemID = @ItemID
                            AND WP.SequenceID = @SequenceID
                            AND WI.ListID = @ListID
                            AND WI.WebID = @WebID
                            AND WI.SiteID = @SiteID
                    ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC;

            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_ItemID INTO @ItemID, @SequenceID, @ListID, @WebID, @SiteID;
        END;

    CLOSE cursor_ItemID;
    DEALLOCATE cursor_ItemID;

    SELECT  *
    FROM    @TempTableStatus;
```

Comment: Going slightly off-topic, but using table variables like `@TempTableStatus` is generally bad idea as it creates issues for query optimizer. You might want to replace it with a temporary table `#TempTableStatus`. That alone might provide you a decent performance gain.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. It's the one I will change in my code. How about the `cursor`? Is it impossible to query without using cursor?

Comment: Looks like you could create a subquery to replace the cursor. But I am not quite sure if the cursor is the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use cursor. Replace it with below query

```
SELECT  ItemID, SequenceID, TaskStatus, ListID, WebID, SiteID
FROM
(
    SELECT  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WP.CurrentActivityTitle,
                                                 WI.ItemID, WP.SequenceID, 
                                                 WI.ListID, WI.WebID, WI.SiteID 
                                    ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC),
            WI.ItemID ,
            WP.SequenceID ,
            CASE WHEN WP.ActivityComplete = 0
                 THEN 'Not Started'
                 ELSE 'Completed'
                 END AS 'TaskStatus' ,
            WI.ListID ,
            WI.WebID ,
            WI.SiteID
    FROM    dbo.WInstance WI
            INNER JOIN dbo.WProgress WP ON WI.InstanceID = WP.InstanceID
    WHERE   WP.CurrentActivityTitle = @AssignTask
) D
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. However, the code doesn't seem to work. I've added the business to make the code more understandable. Could you please give a quick glance on it?

Comment: you need to provide more information on `doesn't work` . Is it syntax error ? the query result is wrong ?

Comment: The query doesn't work due to the missing of `TimeStamp` in `ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC`. I've added `TimeStamp` to the inside `SELECT` query so the result was not correct. (The code was here to get all items without the `distinct` with `order by`).

Comment: This time, it works very well as my expectation. Thanks again for your help.